# On how to apply k means clustering and outlining the clusters

Tags: matlab, time-series, visualization, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am reading about applications of clustering in human motion analysis. I started out with random numbers and applied k-means clustering algorithm but I wanted to have some graphs that circle the clusters as shown in the picture. Basically, the lines represent the motion trajectory. I will appreciate ideas on how to obtain motion trajectory of a person. Application is patient monitoring where the trajectory will be used in abnormal behavior activity.

I will be using a kinect and recording the motion trajectory based on skeleton tracking. So, I will be recording the 4 quaternion values of Head, Shoulder and Torso joints and the RGBD (Red green blue Depth) that is combined as 1 value for these joints. So, a total of 4*3 + 3 = 15 time series. So, there are 15 variables.  How do I convert them to represent the trajectories shown below and then apply clustering to cluster trajectories. The clusters will allow in classification.

Can somebody please show how to obtain the diagram similar to the one attached?[image: Trajectory clustering] and how do I fuse and convert the 15 time series from each person into a single trajectory. 
The picture illustrates the number of clusters that are generated for the time series. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

K-means is a bad fit for *trajectories*.

It needs to be able to **compute the mean** (which is why it is called "k-means"). Having a stable, sensible mean is important. But how meaningful is the mean of some time series, even if you could define it (and the series weren't e.g. of different length, and different movement speed)?

Try hierarchical clustering, and multivariate dynamic time warping.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I will study about them.But since the conversion of 15 time series into a single trajectory will be common no matter what technique I use for clustering, could you shed some ideas on how I can convert 15 time series into a single trajectory like shown in the picture? each line is a trajectory obtained from different moving objects.

Comment: There are similarity measures that quantify the similarity of 15-variate timeseries.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Your answer and comment do not address what I have asked. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Then maybe I don't understand your question. I suggest to use a similarity measure and clustering algorithm more appropriate for clustering 15-variate timeseries, instead of trying to squeeze the data into the points-in-euclidean-space model of k-means.